# How to evaluate the line integral of a vector field?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

a) Show that the following vector-field is conservative
$${\bf F}(x,y) = (1-ye^{-x}){\bf i} + e^{-x}{\bf j}$$

b) Find the potential function $\phi(x,y)$ for ${\bf F}(x,y)$.

c) Evaluate the line integral

$$\int_K{\bf F}\cdot{\rm d}{\bf r}$$

where $K$ is any path from $(0,1)$ to $(\ln(2),2)$. [Problem given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkLpH.png).

---

For part (a), I showed that $\frac{dP}{dy} = -e^{-x} = \frac{dQ}{dx}$

For part (b), I found $f(x,y) = x+ye^{-x}$

But I'm not sure how to solve part (c).

I think I am supposed to parametrize F, but I can't figure out how exactly to do this.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals (also known as [the gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem)) says that if ${\bf F} = \nabla\phi$ then $\int {\bf F}\cdot {\rm d}{\bf r} = \phi(b) - \phi(a)$ where $a,b$ are the start and end points of the curve.

Comment: Your pic is a disaster! :D I can't see anything!

Comment: Images on links do not last forever so please type up the question instead of just posting an image in the future.